# How to add API controller with REST actions using Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to build ASP.NET core 1.0 application which also involves API controller. As far as I know I cannot use `.edmx` files. But how do I add API controller with REST actions using Entity Framework?

I have added all necessary entity frameworks packages in project.json

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
```

When I right click on controller then goto controller option. In Add Scaffold I not getting any options. How to enable option like d API controller with REST actions using Entity Framework?

My environment is VS2015 Professional update3 and a Windows 7 machine.

Thanks & Regards

Vishal

Comment: Thanks @marc_s for correcting typo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be missing these in your `dependencies` section of `project.json`-

```
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
}
```

Add these in dependencies and once these are loaded successfully, check whether you are getting required scaffolding option.

For more information refer this [article](http://www.elanderson.net/2016/07/enable-scaffolding-without-entity-framework-in-asp-net-core/)

See if this helps.